# How to use local video from the folder instead of a Youtube URL?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to have a full page video as my website landing page but currently it only allows me to use Youtube URL's and not local videos, this is okay most of the time but there are certain times when the video doesn't load for some reason.

The code in the anchor tag below

```
<a id="bgndVideo" class="player" data-property="{videoURL:'http://youtu.be/fzz40536QeI?t=10s',containment:'body',autoPlay:true, mute:true, startAt:20, opacity:1}"></a>
```

Help if you can please, I just want to use a video from the local folder only rather than a Youtube video as it should be more reliable.

Comment: What have you tried so far? 'it only allows me to use Youtube URL's' <- _what_ only allows you to use YouTube. Are you using any frameworks or libraries, or is this just plain html and css?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `<video>` tag. Taken from the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video). Granted, the video must exist on the server if you are hosting it.

```
<video controls
       muted
       src="/media/examples/stream_of_water.webm"
       width="300"
       height="200">
    Sorry, your browser doesn't support embedded videos.
</video>

<footer><a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z_4TlZCvYL4">Video</a> by Leonard Lee</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have the file stored locally, you can just add a HTML `video` element:

```
<video src="/path/to.video" poster="/path/to.poster" width="480" controls>
</video>
```